# How to redirect all IE8 users to a specific URL?

Tags: redirects, iis7, windows-server-2008

I have W2008 running IIS and have about 20 websites (all PHP, about half are WP) running on it.

Currently I have this in the header on a few sites and it is working.  But it is getting hard to manage because even though I am the admin there are a lot of developers and they could overwrite the header if they wanted on most sites.

```
<!--[if IE 8]>
<script type="text/javascript">
        window.location = "http://example.com/wedontsupportIE8.html";
    </script>
<![endif]-->
```

Is there a way to set up a rule on the server that would have the same functionality?

**Current rule I have tried:**

I have added rules on web server and they basically don't work right.  I had the redirect to /home/index.php already working for the past 6 months.  When I add the new rule first it does the following:

- in IE8 - 404 error for any directory on site and it reverts to the root
- in IE10, FF, Chrome, Safari - it just redirects to /home as it should.

webconfig below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
        <rules>
  <rule name="IE8rewriteall" patternSyntax="Wildcard">
                    <match url="*" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{HTTP_USER_AGENT}" pattern="*MSIE*" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="http://example.com/ie/index.html" />
                </rule>
            <rule name="Root Hit Redirect" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="^$" />
                <action type="Redirect" url="/home/index.php" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 1):

*Here you go.... this should work:*

```
<rule name="IE8FacePalm" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="\" ignoreCase="true" />
    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny" trackAllCaptures="false">
        <add input="{HTTP_USER_AGENT}" pattern="MSIE 8.0" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="http://x.com/a-url" appendQueryString="false" />
</rule>
```

Comment: Hi bybe - Tried this out and it isn't catching IE8.  Also tried "*MSIE 8.0*" with asterisks.  Also when I add my home redirect rule I get nothing but 500s.  Thanks for your help.